# Ubuntu can only hibernate once?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, lenovo, hibernate

System:

Lenovo Y500 running Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

For some reason, I can only hibernate 1 time after (re)booting up the system.  If I hibernate after the first time, the system goes through all the motions, but returns me to the lock screen.  How can I fix this?